# How do I execute a class in python?

Tags: python, lambda

I have my code here:

```
import json
import logging
import pymysql as pm
import boto3

class ClassName:
    env=None
    config=None

    def DB_connection(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        connection = None
        try:
            host="host"
            port=port
            database="db"

            dbUserName = "user"
            lambdaFunctionName = "lambdafunc"
            client = boto3.client('lambda')
            response = client.invoke(FunctionName=lambdaFunctionName)
            result = json.loads(response['Payload'].read().decode())
            dbPassword = result["secret"]

            connection = pm.connect(user=dbUserName,password=dbPassword,host=host,port=port,database=database)
    
            logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))
        
        return connection
    

    def run_all(self):
        def func1(self):
            func1_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_func1_Insert_Daily_Records();"
            func1_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_func1_Exceptions();"
            with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
                with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                    try:
                        cur.execute(func1_INSERT_QUERY)
                        print("func1 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')

                        cur.execute(func1_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                        print("func1 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
                        data=cur.fetchall()                     
                        for row in data:
                            for col in row:
                                print (col, end=' ')
                            print('\n')

                    except pm.Error as e:
                        print(f"Error: {e}")

                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.exception(e)

                    else:
                        cnxn.commit()
        func1(self)

        def func2(self):
            func2_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_func2_Insert_Daily_Records();"
            func2_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_func2_Exceptions();"
            with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
                with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                    try:
                        cur.execute(func2_INSERT_QUERY)
                        print("func2 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')

                        cur.execute(func2_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                        print("func2 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
                        data=cur.fetchall()                     
                        for row in data:
                            for col in row:
                                print (col, end=' ')
                            print('\n')

                    except pm.Error as e:
                        print(f"Error: {e}")

                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.exception(e)

                    else:
                        cnxn.commit()
        func2(self)

        def func3(self):
            func3_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_func3_Insert_Daily_Records();"
            func3_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_func3_Exceptions();"
            with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
                with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                    try:
                        cur.execute(func3_INSERT_QUERY)
                        print("func3 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')

                        cur.execute(func3_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                        print("func3 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
                        data=cur.fetchall()                   
                        for row in data:
                            for col in row:
                                print (col, end=' ')
                            print('\n')

                    except pm.Error as e:
                        print(f"Error: {e}")

                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.exception(e)

                    else:
                        cnxn.commit()
        func3(self)
```

This code executes a variety of stored procedures that insert data into some tables and create exceptions of other tables. I am just trying to execute this. I already know my stored procedures work, so I need to execute the python piece now.

I want to execute my class. I have a function called "run_all" that executes all of my functions inside that function. How do I execute "run_all"? Or how do I execute my class ClassName?

Comment: You have to create an instance of the class, then call `instance.run_all()`

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to fix the indentation in your code to include the functions in the class.
2. You can fix the function `run_all` as in the following code
3. You can create an object (instance) of your class and call `run_all` by adding the last 2 lines

```py
import json
import logging
import pymysql as pm
import boto3

class ClassName:
    env=None
    config=None

    def DB_connection(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        connection = None
        try:
            host="host"
            port=port
            database="db"

            dbUserName = "user"
            lambdaFunctionName = "lambdafunc"
            client = boto3.client('lambda')
            response = client.invoke(FunctionName=lambdaFunctionName)
            result = json.loads(response['Payload'].read().decode())
            dbPassword = result["secret"]

            connection = pm.connect(user=dbUserName,password=dbPassword,host=host,port=port,database=database)

            logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))
        
        return connection


    def func1(self):
        func1_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_func1_Insert_Daily_Records();"
        func1_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_func1_Exceptions();"
        with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
            with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                try:
                    cur.execute(func1_INSERT_QUERY)
                    print("func1 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')

                    cur.execute(func1_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                    print("func1 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
                    data=cur.fetchall()                     
                    for row in data:
                        for col in row:
                            print (col, end=' ')
                        print('\n')

                except pm.Error as e:
                    print(f"Error: {e}")

                except Exception as e:
                    logging.exception(e)

                else:
                    cnxn.commit()
    def func2(self):
        func2_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_func2_Insert_Daily_Records();"
        func2_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_func2_Exceptions();"
        with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
            with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                try:
                    cur.execute(func2_INSERT_QUERY)
                    print("func2 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')

                    cur.execute(func2_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                    print("func2 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
                    data=cur.fetchall()                     
                    for row in data:
                        for col in row:
                            print (col, end=' ')
                        print('\n')

                except pm.Error as e:
                    print(f"Error: {e}")

                except Exception as e:
                    logging.exception(e)

                else:
                    cnxn.commit()

    def func3(self):
        func3_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_func3_Insert_Daily_Records();"
        func3_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_func3_Exceptions();"
        with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
            with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                try:
                    cur.execute(func3_INSERT_QUERY)
                    print("func3 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')

                    cur.execute(func3_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                    print("func3 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
                    data=cur.fetchall()                   
                    for row in data:
                        for col in row:
                            print (col, end=' ')
                        print('\n')

                except pm.Error as e:
                    print(f"Error: {e}")

                except Exception as e:
                    logging.exception(e)

                else:
                    cnxn.commit()

    def run_all(self):
        self.func1()
        self.func2()
        self.func3()


my_object = ClassName()
my_object.run_all()
```

Comment: thank you, this was very helpful and i was able to understand more about how python instances work!